# Android Camera add text to captured image

Tags: android, image-manipulation, android-camera

I am building an app that takes a picture with the camera, then add some text to the actual image.  Therefore, I can share the image and it will have the text embedded in it.  I've tried many different approaches, but none are working.  Below is my latest attempt which is saving the image, but without the text embedded. There must be a more elegant method than create the bitmap, canvas draw on it, then convert it to an output stream just to save it.  After spending way too long (days) searching tutorials and hacking together their bits and pieces, does anyone have any advice to manipulate a captured image and save it to the sd card?  Should I save the image, then read it and manipulate it, or manipulate it before saving?

```
private PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback() {
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        Bitmap photo = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length).copy(Config.RGB_565, true);

        Canvas canvasView = new Canvas(photo);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setTextSize(52);
        paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);

        canvasView.drawText("Test Text To Add", 0, 0, paint);


        File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile();
        if (pictureFile == null){
            Log.d(logTag, "Error creating media file, check storage permissions");
            releaseCamera();
            return;
        }

        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            photo.compress(CompressFormat.PNG,100, bos);
            byte[] bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray();
            fos.write(bitmapdata);
            fos.close();
            releaseCamera();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.d(logTag, "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
            releaseCamera();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(logTag, e.toString());
            releaseCamera();
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Just got some free time and got back on this long time problem I had. I am interested to see if you found a more elegant solution.